# Definition of the domain - Cauchy theorem - Contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

In general, in that kind of question, there isn't a domain defined (I think). If I ask you to tell me the answer of the contour integral $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-2} dz$ where $\gamma$ is simply the unit circle $C(0,1)$, you will tell me : it's easy by the Cauchy theorem, $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-2} dz = 0$ because $2 > 1$. But according to the definition of the Cauchy theorem, how is defined the domain? Or simply, what is the domain here? **(To know that $\mathbb{C}$ is not the domain.)**

**Cauchy theorem :** Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ a domain, $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function and $C$ a closed path contained with his interior in $D$. Then $\int_C f(z)dz=0$

Comment: I recall you that with the word "domain" one usually denotes a connected open set. Well, the domain is $\Bbb{C} \setminus \{ 2 \}$. Where is the problem?

Comment: The domain is the domain of the function $f$. Here we have $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-2}$. Hence, $f: \Bbb C \setminus \{2\} \to \Bbb C$. The domain is $\Bbb C \setminus \{2\}$. As you pointed out, $C(0,1) \subset \Bbb C \setminus \{2\}$ and $f$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C \setminus \{2\}$. By the Cauchy theorem, the integral therefore vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A domain, or a region, is a connected open set.

The connectedness ensures that the antiderivative is unique up to a constant. The openness ensures that the derivative can be calculated for every point.